# ie9 float left is actually nearer the middle of the page

Tags: css

my sample code below, works in all browsers apart from ie9, in ie9 the leftcolumn is actually nearer the middle of the page for some reason! (im sure if you copy paste you will be able to replicate)

anyone help me out as to why? the css seems fine to me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html, form {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            body {
                font-family:"Segoe UI",Tahoma,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
                font-size:12px;
                color:#333333;

            }
            #container {
                min-width:1200px;
            }
            #horizontal-nav {
                background: #1AA2DE;
                width: 100%;
                height:41px;
            }
            #left-column {
                margin-top:10px;
                width:210px;
                float:left;
            }
            #center-column {
                float:left;
                width:180px;
                margin-top:10px;
            }
            #right-column {
                margin-top:10px;
                float:left;
                margin-left:10px;
            }
            /* TOP NAV */
            .hmenu,
            .hmenu ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin:0;
                padding: 0 0 0 20px;
            }
            .hmenu {
                font-size: 16px;
                float: left;
            }
            .hmenu > li {
                float: left;
            }

            .hmenu li a, .hmenu li span {
                display: block;

                padding: 10px 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .hmenu > li:hover > a {
                background: #5EBEE8;
            }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="horizontal-nav">
                <ul class="hmenu">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="left-column">
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="right-column">
                Right Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Wgtcy/

Comment: Or you could copy/paste for us. Fiddle added.

Comment: My IE9 vm isn't available. Is compatibility mode enabled?

Comment: sorry, turning ON compatibility mode fixed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positioning of the horizontal-nav div is throwing off your subsequent floats in the container div in IE9. Give your horizontal-nav div a `float: left;` to fix.

Unless you plan on creating a fixed header you should always have block-level elements playing by the same positioning rules. Since you are using `float:left;` for the other block elements then this will fix on ALL machines, regardless of weird configs people are running in random browsers.